# Add a row to a patient in dataset based on value of data in preceding rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset structured in this way:

```
Patient ID    Visit Date         Dead     Death Date    Sex    State
101           Feb/14             1          Jan/15      M      2
101           June/14            1          Jan/15      M      3 
101           December/14        1          Jan/15      M      2
102           Jan/14             0          N/A         M      1
102           April/14           0          N/A         M      1
```

If the patient has died, all visits will be tagged with the "Dead" code and a death date.

If the death code is =1

I need a row created as the last visit for patient 101

with the death date in the "Visit Date Column"

and the "State" variable indicating 5 (code for the state of death in my dataset).

The dataset I want will look like this (the 4th line of data is the important one):

```
Patient ID    Visit Date         Dead     Death Date    Sex    State
101           Feb/14             1          Jan/15      M      2
101           June/14            1          Jan/15      M      3 
101           December/14        1          Jan/15      M      2
101           Jan/15             1          Jan/15      M      5 
102           Jan/14             0          N/A         M      1
102           April/14           0          N/A         M      1
```

Comment: it doesn't matter that you put it in the right place--just add the row to the end and then sort by patient ID and visit date

Comment: @rawr fair point, I changed the question to reflect your comment. However, I do need the Death Date to Populate the visit date column in the new row and the state to register as 5. Could you help with this aspect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things going on. First you should use `NA` instead of character strings. Second, you should format those dates so you can work with them (and sort by them properly).

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "ID    Visit         Dead     Death    Sex    State
101           Feb/14             1          Jan/15      M      2
101           June/14            1          Jan/15      M      3 
101           December/14        1          Jan/15      M      2
102           Jan/14             0          N/A         M      1
102           April/14           0          N/A         M      1 ",
                  na.strings = 'N/A')

## format dates helper
f_dt <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  res <- sprintf('01/%s/%s', substr(x, 1, 3), gsub('\\D', '', x))
  as.Date(res, '%d/%b/%y')
}

dat <- within(dat, {
  Visit <- f_dt(Visit)
  Death <- f_dt(Death)
})

## remove those not dead and take the last row
## assign values how you want
deaths <- dat[with(dat, !is.na(Death) & !duplicated(ID, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
deaths <- within(deaths, {
  Visit <- Death
  State <- 5
})

## combine everything and order
out <- rbind(dat, deaths)
out[with(out, order(ID, Visit)), ]

#     ID      Visit Dead      Death Sex State
# 1  101 2014-02-01    1 2015-01-01   M     2
# 2  101 2014-06-01    1 2015-01-01   M     3
# 3  101 2014-12-01    1 2015-01-01   M     2
# 31 101 2015-01-01    1 2015-01-01   M     5
# 4  102 2014-01-01    0       <NA>   M     1
# 5  102 2014-04-01    0       <NA>   M     1
```

Comment: apologies for being a pain, the dates are formatted using the chron package in R

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='Patient_ID    Visit_Date         Dead     Death_Date    Sex    State
101           Feb/14             1          Jan/15      M      2
101           June/14            1          Jan/15      M      3 
101           December/14        1          Jan/15      M      2
102           Jan/14             0          N/A         M      1
102           April/14           0          N/A         M      1 ', stringsAsFactors=F)

df$Patient_ID <- as.numeric(df$Patient_ID) #this needs to be numeric

df <- rbind(df, list(101, 'Jan/15', 1, 'Jan/15', 'M', 5 )) #use rbind to add a row

> df[order(df$Patient_ID),] #sort on Patient ID and the last row is inserted where it should
  Patient_ID  Visit_Date Dead Death_Date Sex State
1        101      Feb/14    1     Jan/15   M     2
2        101     June/14    1     Jan/15   M     3
3        101 December/14    1     Jan/15   M     2
6        101      Jan/15    1     Jan/15   M     5
4        102      Jan/14    0        N/A   M     1
5        102    April/14    0        N/A   M     1
```

So, the only thing that you really need to use is use the `rbind` function which adds a row at the end of a data.frame. Use it as `rbind( <your_data.frame> , <a vector with the values to add>).` In our case `<your data frame>` is df and  `<a vector with the values to add>` is `list(101, 'Jan/15', 1, 'Jan/15', 'M', 5 )`.

It is better to use a list vector to add the row because this will make sure that your data.frame's column types will remain the same. Using an atomic vector will coerce everything to character.

Comment: there are over 3000 unique patients and the dataframe contains 23 variables the could you provide a scalable set of instructions?

Comment: @Mark Not sure what kind of instructions you mean Mark. I will gladly add instructions according to what you need. After adding the row with `rbind` sorting by `Patient_ID` will always put the last line at the end of the grouped data i.e. at the end of `Patient_ID=101` in this occasion. Isn't this what you needed? Please specify how you would like this to work and I will gladly try to improve my code above (and maybe write a function for example)

Comment: Would you like to be able to add the row in a specific location maybe which will be set by you?

Comment: Apologies, I am getting quite confused now.

The specific location of the row should not be an issue because I can sort by patient ID and visit date.

What I really need is a new row when death is indicated and the death date recorded in the visit date column. And also the number 5 for the death state variable.

Comment: No worries :). There really isn't a set of instructions to use :). Just use the function `rbind` to add the row at the end of your dataframe. You just use `rbind( <your_data.frame> , c(<comma delimited values for the last row) )`. And that's it really :P. I will add an explanation at the end of my answer.

Comment: So, unless you need something extra (in which case let me know) I think the above solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A data table answer:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='Patient_ID    Visit_Date         Dead     Death_Date    Sex    State
101           Feb/14             1          Jan/15      M      2
101           June/14            1          Jan/15      M      3 
101           December/14        1          Jan/15      M      2
102           Jan/14             0          N/A         M      1
102           April/14           0          N/A         M      1 ', stringsAsFactors=F)

library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
# take only the Patient_ID, Death indicator, Death date and sex 
dead <- unique(DT[ Death_Date != "N/A", c(1, 3, 4, 5), with = FALSE, ])

# move the death date to visited, assign '5' to state
dead[, c("Visit_Date", "State") := list(Death_Date, 5)  ]

# recombine with original records
records <- rbind(DT, dead)
records[ order(records$Patient_ID, as.Date(records$Visit_Date, format = "%b/%d")),]
   Patient_ID  Visit_Date Dead Death_Date Sex State
1:        101      Jan/15    1     Jan/15   M     5
2:        101      Feb/14    1     Jan/15   M     2
3:        101     June/14    1     Jan/15   M     3
4:        101 December/14    1     Jan/15   M     2
5:        102      Jan/14    0        N/A   M     1
6:        102    April/14    0        N/A   M     1
```

Comment: this part `as.Date(records$Visit_Date, format = "%b/%d")` should have been tested

Comment: @rawr ... do you not see the output? Runs just fine